# Category item on navigation Menu - Wordpress Twentyeleven

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation, wordpress-theming

```
<nav id="access" role="navigation">
    <h3 class="assistive-text">Main menu</h3>
    <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#content" title="Skip to primary content">Skip to primary content</a></div>
    <div class="skip-link"><a class="assistive-text" href="#secondary" title="Skip to secondary content">Skip to secondary content</a></div>
    <div class="menu-hello-container">
    <ul id="menu-hello" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-10" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10"><a href="http://tyutoryals.nazuka.net/contact/">Contact</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-9" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-9"><a href="http://tyutoryals.nazuka.net/about-us/">About</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-175" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-175"><a href="http://tyutoryals.nazuka.net/category/know-how/">Know-How</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-8" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-8"><a href="http://tyutoryals.nazuka.net">Home</a></li>
    </ul></div>
</nav>
```

One my my category item set as a menu bar, that item is the **Know-How** on the **HTML code** above..The problem is when this menu is active it's not colored in something red...

Here is the CSS code for it..

```
#access .current-menu-item > a, 
#access .current-menu-ancestor > a, 
#access .current_page_item > a, 
#access .current_page_ancestor > a { 
    font-weight: bold; 
    color: white; 
    background: #D03C3C;
}
```

I think the problem is because it is a **category item** not a **Page**..but i don't what to do with the CSS

Comment: add the class `current-menu-item` to the item you want to be marked as selected and remove the class from the other items

Comment: that CSS code is working with other menus, except with the **Know-How**..